# Do we need "more than 200 reputation" instead of "at least 200 reputation" to get the silver "Yearling" badge?

Tags: bug, reputation, yearling-badge

I have observed this on [ask ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) community, but this probably applies to all communities on [StackExchange](https://stackexchange.com/sites).

On March 2, 2019, I scored *200 reputation* and I did not receive the silver *"Yearling"* badge.

On March 4, 2019, [I got 2 new points](https://askubuntu.com/users/588848/simhumileco?tab=reputation), so now I have *202 reputation* and I immediately got the *"Yearling"* badge.

My case shows that to get the silver *"Yearling"* badge we must have ***"over 200 reputation"***, not ***"at least 200 reputation"***, as it is written for example [here](https://askubuntu.com/help/badges/13/yearling?userid=588848):

Is this what it should be like, or maybe I misunderstand something?

Comment: Thank you @MSOGA! It explains case with "Yearling" badge :)

Comment: @MSOGA If you want, you can give an answer.

Comment: @simhumileco no, two questions in one question is wrong. The question here now is about the wrong wording in the reputation league, and that alone. If you want to ask about the (not) wrong wording for Yearling, please start a new question for that.

Comment: OK, thank you @ShadowWizard I'll do it soon.

Comment: I didn't know in the begin that there are two different cases. I split these question in two, the second is here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/324782/in-fact-there-are-more-than-200-reputation-instead-of-at-least-200-reputatio as you suggest @ShadowWizard

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to *earn* 200 reputation.  The first point of rep comes with your account and does not count toward the Yearling badge.

Comment: MSOGA might want to get some credit too: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/324777/do-we-need-more-than-200-reputation-instead-of-at-least-200-reputation-to-ge#comment1060742_324777 :)

Comment: @MEEthesetupwizard oh, I didn't read the comments.  Answers belong in answers, so I didn't see the answer in a comment.