# In fact, we need "more than 200 reputation" instead of "at least 200 reputation" for "tracked in the leagues"

Tags: bug, reputation, reputation-leagues

## The original question:

I have observed this on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) community, but this probably applies to all communities on [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/sites).

On March 2, 2019, I scored *200 reputation* and I was not *"tracked in the leagues"*.

On March 4, 2019, [I got two new points](https://askubuntu.com/users/588848/simhumileco?tab=reputation), so now I have *202 reputation points* and I am *"tracked in the leagues"* now.

My case shows that to be *"tracked in the leagues"* we must have ***"over 200 reputation points"***, not ***"at least 200 reputation points"***, as it is written for example [here](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/89/alltime/askubuntu):

[image]

So ***"users with less than 200 reputation points are not tracked in the leagues"*** *(<200)* should means **"users with at least 200 reputation points are tracked in the leagues"** *(>=200)*, isn't it?

Is this what it should be like, or maybe I misunderstand something?

#### Update after receiving negative points:

I think there is a misunderstanding here...

I want to explain that I understand perfectly well that people who have a reputation less than 200 are not tracked in the leagues, and people who have a reputation above 200 are tracked in the leagues.

**I also understand the phrases *"less than"* and *"at least"* and the fact that they are *opposites* and the fact that the opposite of *"less than"* is *"greater than or equal"* NOT ONLY *"greater than"*...** This is obvious to me.

I only notice that the statements contained on the Stack Exchange pages show that users which **have *200* reputation points should be tracked in the leagues (look at the red frame on the above screenshot), but in my experience, it is not**...

I don't insist that this is how it should be. It just seems to be incorrectly.

**I think that many people may have doubts like me.**

**If I'm wrong, I'm asking for an explanation in the answer. But if I'm right, I've noticed the inconsistency in Stack Exchange, which may be important for many thousands of users who have exactly 200 reputations.**

**I do it with care for the Stack Exchange and its community**, and the community gives me a lot of negative points for it... I do not understand it a bit.

Comment: This question was arranged as a result of the division of this question:
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/324777/do-we-need-more-than-200-reputation-instead-of-at-least-200-reputation-to-ge
for two different questions.

Comment: Why is this question getting negative points? Can anyone explain it to me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I cannot reproduce this issue. The reputation league page consists of [several](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/89/alltime/askubuntu/2010-07-28?sort=reputationchange&page=464) users with exactly 200 reputation.

I think the reason you were running into this is because the reputation league page is heavily cached on the order of a few days, for users who become eligible or ineligible to be tracked. In your case, the cache didn't update until you had already earned those two extra points, pushing you to 202.

The wording is correct here.

Answer (score 1):

At least and less than are kinda opposite.

As is, the wording is accurate -

If user > 200 reputation then user is not shown.

At least is means equal to or greater than.

Comment: Your reflection is generally correct, but it probably does not refer to what is written on the stackexchange pages:

"users with less than 200 reputation are not tracked in the leagues"...

If I'm wrong, please lead me out of error.

Comment: If you have 200 or less you are not tracked. Hit 201 and you are. It's correct

Comment: I understand, but there is written "users with less than 200 reputation are not tracked in the leagues". Is it correct? Thank you for your patience @JourneymanGeek

Comment: And they are not tracked

Comment: The statement in the red box in the question says <200 are not, but the wording you quote says not if >200. Those are not exactly the same. At least, neither I nor the OP think they are the same.

Comment: The opposite of "less than" is "greater than or equal" NOT ONLY "greater than"... Please read "Update after receiving negative points" section in this question.